# How to implement the infinite scrolling when scrolling upwards(e.g. load earlier messages)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, infinite-scroll

I'm learning to create a simple web chat where I want to implement infinite scrolling for loading earlier messages. I have tried to implement the infinite scrolling but it only works when scrolled to the bottom not when scrolling upwards to view the old messages.

As for the messages it is hardcoded as for now and I tried getting user input as well instead of hardcoding them. Moreover, if the user is reading the old messages then it will auto scroll to the bottom to display new messages.

Can I tweak the code I used for infinite scrolling on the bottom to be applied to infinite scrolling on upwards? Or, is there any other way of doing it?

Infinite scroll to the bottom :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(".chatlogs").scroll(function(){
    if($(this).scrollTop() + $(this).innerHeight() >= $(this) 
        [0].scrollHeight){
        //appended div items.   
    }
})
</script>
```

To view the latest messages instead of old messages on page load:

```
 <script>
 window.onload=function () {
     var objDiv = document.getElementById("logbox");
     objDiv.scrollTop = objDiv.scrollHeight;
 }
 </script>
```

Autoscroll to the bottom when receiving new messages:

```
$(".chatlogs").stop().animate({ scrollTop: $(".chatlogs")[0].scrollHeight}, 1000);
```

CSS:

```
.chatlogs {
    padding: 10px;
    width: 100%;
    max-height: 450px;
    overflow-x:hidden;
    overflow-y:scroll;
    background :#efe7dd
}

.chatlogs::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width:10px;
}

.chatlogs::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    border-radius: 5px;
    background: #b3ada7;
}
```

Comment: Maybe you could have a look at my answer to this question, I’ve explain how to accomplish a infinite scrolling in ReactJS. https://stackoverflow.com/a/49860137/9633730

Comment: Thanks for your help but I'm trying to use jquery for this. Yet to explore any frameworks.

Comment: All good. But I want you to know that the basic principle for the  implementation of infinite scroll, no matter what framework you are using. 1. listen to the scroll event 2. set the bottom line of your container 3. check whether the bottom line is whiting the view point.

Comment: Thank you for the previous comment. As I'm still a beginner with JS, I found implementing infinite scroll is seems to be bit tricky and confusing. I do need more basic understanding it seems. Managed to get the scroll down to work yet just challenging myself by trying to do that inversely.

Comment: cool. If you have more questions about it, feel free to ask me :)

Comment: Alright sure, thank you.